# React Native offline functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Will my React Native app work offline if I store all the downloaded animations, including audio, in the assets folder, and if I save all the questions in arrays?

I wanted to know if it's not then I will use database,and what database to use ,like this app should be offline

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, assets such as images, videos, and other resources used in a React Native app can work offline.** Once the assets are downloaded and stored on the device, they can be accessed and displayed even when the app is not connected to the internet.

React Native allows developers to bundle assets into the app during the build process, which means they are **included in the app package that is downloaded onto the device**. This enables the app to access those assets without requiring an internet connection.

However, it's worth noting that any features of the app that require internet connectivity, such as fetching data from an API or making network requests, will not work when the device is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Storing all the ... can make your React Native app work offline.

However, if you're looking for a better solution, using a database may be a better option. You could use a lightweight database like SQLite.

By using a database, you can store and manage more complex data structures and query the data more efficiently.